# Cannot uninstall MiKTeX from Windows 8.1

Tags: miktex, texlive, installing

My MiKTeX installation isn't working properly and I want to reinstall it. But I cannot uninstall it using either 'Control Panel' or the 'uninstall.exe' file in the internal folder. I get a Windows error message at every turn. Updates are also not working. I just need a running LaTeX installation and fast.

1. How can I uninstall MiKTeX?
2. If I must delete files manually, which files would that be?
3. Can I install another distribution without disturbing my existing MiKTeX install?
4. If I have to, say, format everything and then install MikTex, what could I possibly do to avoid such a situation again?

Comment: You can uninstall MikTeX as any other program you have in computer. Go to control panel, open Uninstall Programs under  Programs. Select MikTeX and select key Uninstall.

Comment: you can install TeX Live 2016 parallel to your MiKTeX distribution and simply switch compilers and other commands in your editor. Alternative: if really urgent use ShareLaTeX or Overleaf, as these are online based and only need a web browser.

Comment: @Zarko No, that isn't working. It gives a Windows API error.

Comment: @naphaneal I use Texnicenter as the editor. Will making the switch be difficult? I have zero knowhow about things like this

Comment: follow the manual and you should be fine: http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/configuration.html

Comment: @naphaneal I can't seem to install TeXlive. It just stops about 10 minutes into the installation. But thankfully, a MikTeX update just worked when I changed the mirror and everything seems working again. *phew*